# MongoDB: stuck on complex query... Update an array inside an object

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB object:

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("508ec9f413f88da4a590e5ee"),
   "beersAndStouts": {
     "0": {
       "description": "Guinness",
       "price": "4.20"
    },
     "1": {
       "description": "Heineken",
       "price": "4.80"
    },
     "2": {
       "description": "Carlsberg",
       "price": "4.80"
    }
  },
   "snacks": {
     "0": {
       "description": "King cheese and onion",
       "price": "2.20"
    },
     "1": {
       "description": "Tayto cheese and onion",
       "price": "1.80"
    }
  },
   "specialOffers": {
     "0": {
       "description": "Two for one vodka\/red bull",
       "price": "8"
    }
  },
   "uname": "Eamorr",
   "wines": {
     "0": {
       "description": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
       "price": "5.00"
    },
     "1": {
       "description": "Chardonnay",
       "price": "5.00"
    }
  }
}
```

and I have the following PHP variables:

```
$category=$_POST['category'];   //"beersAndStouts"
$description=$_POST['columnName'];   //"Description"
$value=$_POST['value'];   //"4.70"
$rowId=$_POST['rowId'];   //2
```

I want to change the price of Carlsberg (rowId=2) from 4.80 to 4.70...

How to run such a query?

Here's what I have sofar, but I'm really stuck now...

```
$priceLists=$mongo->eamorr->priceLists;
$priceLists->update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array($category=>array($rowId=>xxx))));
```

---

Update: here is the code I used:

```
$mongo=new Mongo();
$priceLists=$mongo->eamorr->priceLists;

$priceList=$priceLists->findOne(array('uname'=>$uname));

$newCategory=$priceList[$category];
$newCategory[$rowId][$description]=$value;

$priceLists->update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array($category=>$newCategory)));
```

It's not pretty, but it works and I don't have to change my structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need it to be an object of objects?
You can substitute it with array of objects and in such a case it will work just fine
Here is the idea:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("508ec9f413f88da4a590e7ee"),
  "beersAndStouts" : [{
      "description" : "Guinness",
      "price" : "4.20"
    }, {
      "description" : "Heineken",
      "price" : 6666
    }, {
      "description" : "Carlsberg",
      "price" : "4.80"
    }],
  "snacks" : [{
      "description" : "King cheese and onion",
      "price" : "2.20"
    }, {
      "description" : "Tayto cheese and onion",
      "price" : "1.80"
    }],
  "specialOffers" : [{
      "description" : "Two for one vodka/red bull",
      "price" : "8"
    }],
  "uname" : "Eamorr",
  "wines" : [{
      "description" : "Cabernet Sauvignon",
      "price" : "5.00"
    }, {
      "description" : "Chardonnay",
      "price" : "5.00"
    }]
}
```

And the query in such a case is simple:

```
db.test.update({
   "_id" : ObjectId("508ec9f413f88da4a590e7ee"),
   "beersAndStouts.description" : "Carlsberg"
},{
  '$set' : {
  'beersAndStouts.$.price' :  4.70
}
});
```

keep in mind that I changed ObjectId!

Put this in your mongo shell and it works.

I hope adjusting it to php is obvious.

Comment: Yes, objects of objects is redundant... I'll have to look again at how I'm storing this information. Thanks so much for your reply.